# on click a button how i set myglsurfaceview dynamically

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I had done a `glSurfaceView` embedded inside a layout using android, and there are some buttons on the leftside of `glSurfaceView`. By clicking that button a new `glSurfaceView` should be created on the previous one.

How could I do that? As in this `com.example.activity.MyGlSurfaceView` is always constant, how can I make it dynamically change it?

```
 <Linearlayout .....>

  <include android:id="@+id/title_btn"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1"
    layout="@layout/option_button"/>

   <com.example.activity.MyGlSurfaceView
         android:id="@+id/gl_surface_view"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_weight="8"/> 
       </Linearlayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope it could be the answer for your question

```
MyGlSurfaceView sv = (MyGlSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.gl_surface_view);

yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        sv = new MySurfaceView(yourContext);
    }
});
```

this is my first answer XD

Added:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    MyGLSurfaceView myGl;
    Button button;
    Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context= this;
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        myGl = (MyGLSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.main_gl);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.main_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myGl = new MyGLSurfaceView(context);
            }
        });
    }
}



public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setRenderer(new MyRenderer());
    }

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setRenderer(new MyRenderer());
    }   
    static class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{

        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
            gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
        }

        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
            gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
        }


    }
}

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <com.renderer.test.MyGLSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/main_gl"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am not sure this would suit for your case but it doesn't make error on my phone.

Comment: but if i click another button then in setonclickListener, sv=new mynewglsurfaceview(context); then myrenderer render=new myrenderer()this; sv.setrenderer(render); this gives an error as the object is already renderered.

Comment: I added more codes. hope this would be what you are looking for

Comment: i want on one button click it will go to one renderer and by clicking another button it will go to another renderer and also if nothing is click it will go show a default renderer,how this will be possible.Thanks your code helps me to understand more clearly